# Debugging Laravel 4.2 with PHPStorm 9 and XAMPP

Tags: laravel, xampp, phpstorm

I am using Laravel 4.2, with the public directory being `/htdocs` and the logic files are kept in `/htdocs/../soft`. I am using PHPStorm 9 to debug this app. I've set the interpreter to `php.exe` from the XAMPP package, and in the Deployment stettings I've added a `Local or mounted folder` deployment with `Upload/download project files` set to `C:\xampp\htdocs`. I've added the `htdocs/../soft` into the Directories of the project in PHPStorm.

Debugging does work for `/htdocs/index.php` when debugging the file itself `debug index.php`, but not when debugging using the browser. How do I configure PHPStorm to debug this directory structure "in browser". I got `xdebug` installed and the JBeans extension as well.

Comment: 1) Proof that xdebug is installed (`phpinfo()` output -- header part + xdebug section) 2) What it "JBeans extension" and why do you need it

Comment: Actual manuals: 1) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm 2) https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/quickstart/debugger.html 3) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Installing+and+Configuring+XAMPP+with+PhpStorm+IDE